# Texture paint on both sides of a mirrored object?

Tags: texture-painting

I was texture painting a mirror modified mesh and wanted to customize the look of the left arm to the right. But, since the mesh is mirror modified it paints symmetrical. I saw online that you can't generate individual UV cords for each side due to being mirrored but you can use the U and V modifiers inside the mirror modifier. Though, when using them I got weird issues where painting on one face would also paint on a random the other(almost like overlapping) when none of the uv maps were overlapping. Is there a way to be able to texture paint each side differently? Thanks.